Creating columns from a column that contains a list of dictionaries
I have a dataframe that has a column with a list of dictionaries that look like this object
[{'MetricName': 'test:mean_wQuantileLoss',
  'Value': 1.0935583114624023,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
 {'MetricName': 'train:loss:batch',
  'Value': 3.0625627040863037,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
 {'MetricName': 'train:progress',
  'Value': 100.0,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
 {'MetricName': 'train:loss',
  'Value': 3.2942464351654053,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
 {'MetricName': 'train:final_loss',
  'Value': 3.2942464351654053,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
 {'MetricName': 'train:throughput',
  'Value': 385.56353759765625,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
 {'MetricName': 'test:RMSE',
  'Value': 22.101428985595703,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6, tzinfo=tzlocal())},
 {'MetricName': 'ObjectiveMetric',
  'Value': 22.101428985595703,
  'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6, tzinfo=tzlocal())}]

I want to create columns for each MetricName and what the Value is. I have other columns in the dataframe that I want to keep in tact as well. How do I achieve this?
Here is a sample dataframe
data = {'TrainingJobName': ['Training_JOB_NAME1'],
       'TrainingJobArn': ["Blahblah"],
       'FinalMetricDataList': ["[{'MetricName': 'test:mean_wQuantileLoss', 'Value': 1.0935583114624023, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'MetricName': 'train:loss:batch', 'Value': 3.0625627040863037, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'MetricName': 'train:progress', 'Value': 100.0, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'MetricName': 'train:loss', 'Value': 3.2942464351654053, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'MetricName': 'train:final_loss', 'Value': 3.2942464351654053, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'MetricName': 'train:throughput', 'Value': 385.56353759765625, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'MetricName': 'test:RMSE', 'Value': 22.101428985595703, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, {'MetricName': 'ObjectiveMetric', 'Value': 22.101428985595703, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6, tzinfo=tzlocal())}]"]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_sample.head()


Data in question are in 8 rows or in one? Can you add some data sample of DataFrame?

A [mre] should have both example input and the desired results (please read the link)

Can different rows, in your initial dataframe, have different metrics that need columns creating? Could row1 have a metric name that's not mentioned in row2?

You can use DataFrame.explode for convert list of dictionaries to rows, json_normalize for new columns, pivot them by DataFrame.pivot and append to existing data by DataFrame.join:
import datetime as datetime

data = {'TrainingJobName': ['Training_JOB_NAME1'],
       'TrainingJobArn': ["Blahblah"],
       'FinalMetricDataList': [[{'MetricName': 'test:mean_wQuantileLoss', 'Value': 1.0935583114624023, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6)}, {'MetricName': 'train:loss:batch', 'Value': 3.0625627040863037, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37)}, {'MetricName': 'train:progress', 'Value': 100.0, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37)}, {'MetricName': 'train:loss', 'Value': 3.2942464351654053, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37)}, {'MetricName': 'train:final_loss', 'Value': 3.2942464351654053, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37)}, {'MetricName': 'train:throughput', 'Value': 385.56353759765625, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 44, 37)}, {'MetricName': 'test:RMSE', 'Value': 22.101428985595703, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6)}, {'MetricName': 'ObjectiveMetric', 'Value': 22.101428985595703, 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 20, 7, 45, 6)}]]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
#print (df_sample)

df = df_sample.explode('FinalMetricDataList')
out = pd.json_normalize(df['FinalMetricDataList']).assign(idx = df.index.tolist())

out = df_sample.join(out.pivot(index='idx', columns='MetricName', values='Value'))
print (out)
0  Training_JOB_NAME1       Blahblah   

                                 FinalMetricDataList  ObjectiveMetric  \
0  [{'MetricName': 'test:mean_wQuantileLoss', 'Va...        22.101429   

   test:RMSE  test:mean_wQuantileLoss  train:final_loss  train:loss  \
0  22.101429                 1.093558          3.294246    3.294246   

   train:loss:batch  train:progress  train:throughput  
0          3.062563           100.0        385.563538  


I have other columns in the dataframe, is there a way to keep those in tact?

@Wolfy - Can you add some example like df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[L], 'val':[45]}) ?

Just edited the question with a sample

@Wolfy - are data in string in FinalMetricDataList column? Or are like in my data sample in edited answer?

Well its a list,

This works but I am probably making the wrong object type

@wolfy "[{'x': 'y'}, {'a', 'b'}]" isn't a list, it's a string. In your question the first example doesn't have quotes around the list, but the second example does. The quotes being there or not matters.  Being a string or a list matters.
